# exact meaning of feeling a bit off colour in British English?

Tags: idioms

What does it mean for a Brit to say "I'm feeling a bit off colour today."?

An Australian told me it could mean "upset," but I find his explanation contrary to dictionary definition. So I was trying to seek more feedback here.

Could it be that the dictionary fails to reflect the reality here?

I'd appreciate comments from Brits.